# Springboot configure requests based on class attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, httprequest

Im trying to create a employee managing system whilist studying spring security. I created a class employee, which has an attribute 'role'.
I want to limit the user's requests based on what the role is : whether it's an admin, supervisor etc.

I found some answers, but it seems it's more related to different classes rather than different attributes within a class.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Permissions implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissionsList")
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    private String title;
    private String permission_description;

    public Permissions(Long id, String title, String permission_description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.permission_description = permission_description;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "roles_permissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")
    )
    private List<Permissions> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Role(Long id, String title, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Role() {
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @TableGenerator(name = "User_Gen", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "User_Gen", initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 100)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "User_Gen")
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message ="Mandatory to fill in")
    @Length(min=5, max=20, message ="Size should be between 5 and 20")
    private String name;
    private String username;
    @NotEmpty(message ="Mandatory to fill in")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    @NotNull(message ="Mandatory to fill in")
    private Integer salary;
    @NotEmpty(message ="Mandatory to fill in")
    @Length(min=5, max=20, message ="Size should be between 5 and 20")
    private String email;
    private LocalDate date_of_birth;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String emergencyPhoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Leave> leaves = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee(
            Long id,
            String name,
            String password,
            Role role,
            Integer salary,
            String email,
            LocalDate date_of_birth,
            String address,
            String phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password=password;
        this.role = role;
        this.email = email;
        this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.salary=salary;
    }

    public Integer getTotalHolidaysTaken(){

        AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);

        getLeaves().stream()
                .forEach(l -> {
                    if (l.getLeaveType().getCode()==1){
                        count.updateAndGet(v -> Math.toIntExact(v + DAYS.between(l.getLeaveFrom(), l.getLeaveTo())));
                    }
                });


        return count.get();


    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private CustomEmployeeDetailsService employeeDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;


    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/authenticate-employee",
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST = {



    };


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
                userDetailsService(employeeDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, for example, if the employee is a Hiring Manager, they can add new employees to the system or delete them(which are going to be configured by the permissions when the role is created). But I don't want every employee to have these rights.

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Security 5.5, you can [use an `AuthorizationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#_the_authorizationmanager) to enforce your authorization rules.

The following code assumes that `Employee` attributes are accessible from the current `Authentication` object.

#### AuthorizationManager

Instead of:

```java
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
```

you can do:

```java
public class MyAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {
    private final String role;

    // ... constructor

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext context) {
        Employee employee = (Employee) authentication.get().getPrincipal();
        // check role
    }

    public static MyAuthorizationManager hasRole(String role) {
        return new MyAuthorizationManager(role);
    }
}

...

http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().access(hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

#### SpEL expression

Or, you before 5.5, you can instead publish a custom `@Bean` and refer to it in a SpEL expression:

```java
@Component("authz")
public class MyAuthorizationBean {
    @Override
    public boolean hasRole(Authentication authentication, String role) {
        Employee employee = (Employee) authentication.get().getPrincipal();
        // check role
    }
}

...

http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("@authz.hasRole(authentication, 'ROLE_ADMIN')");
```

#### UserDetailsService

Or, you can adapt your authorization model into Spring Security's in your custom `UserDetailsService`. The idea here is that you'd look up the user's roles and permissions at authentication time and translate them into `GrantedAuthority` instances:

```java
@Component
public class CustomEmployeeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final EmployeeService employees;

    @Override
    public UserDetails findUserByUsername(String username) {
        Employee employee = // ... lookup
        return new EmployeeAdapter(employee);
    }

    private static final class EmployeeAdapter extends Employee implements UserDetails {
        private final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

        EmployeeAdapter(Employee employee) {
            super(employee);
            String role = employee.getRole().getTitle();
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
            this.authorities = Collections.singleton(authority);
        }

        // ... implement `UserDetails` methods

        @Override
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return this.authorities;
        }
    }
}
```

While a bit more leg-work, the nice thing about this is then you can use Spring Security's native representation like so:

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

Since the built-in `hasRole`/`hasAuthority`/etc. use the authentication's `GrantedAuthority` list. It's also nice that all that translation work is done one time up-front when the user logs in.